# Find Facebook account attached to iPhone

Tags: ios, acaccount, acaccountstore

I am working on a sample project, where I need to find Facebook account stored in settings app.I am using `Facebook SDK`. I have tried using `ACAccountStore` but it returns an empty `NSArray` of accounts. Is this the right way or am I missing something.

Comment: Post your code. Without it, your question can be closed cause its too broad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some investigation on Facebook SDK I found a solution. The path which I was following was different and the thing that I found after some investigation was different but a easy one. Facebook provides.

1. [FacebookLoginView](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios#button-overview): Uses prebuilt ui components to authenticate user stored in Facebook app.
2. [FBSession](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios/v2.0):Facebook login to your app using your own custom UI for the login and logout controls

Answer (score 0):

Did you look into PFUser?

```
[PFUser currentUser]
```

https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFUser.html